# How can I register a css page from an ascx control?

Tags: asp.net, css, ascx

How can I register a css code block inside an ascx control?

Can I just have

```
<head id="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .customClass
        {
        background-color: Lime;
        }

        </style>
</head>
```

Anywhere in ascx page? I doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Including CSS rules within your `head` tag like you are showing will indeed work, but I'm not sure what you mean by "anywhere in ascx page." HTML pages can only have a single `head` tag, so if you're inserting that snippet inside your user control, the markup will not be valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [three options to insert CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) into a page:

- External style sheet
- Internal style sheet
- Inline style

The `style` element must be enclosed within the `head` element. If you are attempting to style elements contained within a user control you can use any of these three options. As a note (mostly my opinion) inline styling is 99.9% of the time the wrong decision.

One option is to expose a `ContentPlaceHolder` in your Site.Master inside the head section. Then using this `ContentPlaceHolder` on pages where you use your user control you'll be able to place a `link` element specifying a style sheet for your user control.

Another option is to simply put the styling rules for your user control in the style sheet used for your entire site.

Answer (score 7):

Styles must be defined in the `head` section of your HTML. That goes for both `style` tags and `link` tags that register external CSS files.

If your page has a `head` tag with the `runat="server"` attribute, you can programmatically access it via the property `this.Page.Header`.

The method I usually use when I need to add something between the opening `<head>` and closing `</head>` tag is a method such as this one. Simply pass in the url to your stylesheet.

```
public void AddStylesheet(string url)
{
    string link = String.Format("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"{0}\" />", url);
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl { Text = link });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <style type="text/css">
       @import url(user_stylesheet.css)
       .customClass
        {
            background-color: Lime;
        }

    </style>
```

In this case the css will only be rendered when usercontrol rendered.